# How to Merge Branch1-repo1 with Branch1-repo2 where only folder structure is changed?

Tags: git, merge

I am in a tough spot - would appreciate any sort of help. 
Here is the back story - 
there is a repo, where the folder structure is something like

Repo1
Some path
.A
..X1
...some path
....X2


Repo2
Same exact path as repo1
.A
..Y1
...exactly the same path as repo1
....Y2

I had taken a physical copy of this repo, and had renamed X1 and Y, before creating a new repo. I know, I was stupid to do that, but lets not fret on this.
Considerable development has gone into both the repos. I would like to merge repo1 into repo2 (Even if history of repo1 is not preserved in repo2 i.e if it is one giant merge commit i am totally fine - since history of repo1 was never in repo2)

There are atleast a thousand files that i would like to merge - otherwise i could have done it manually.

Is there anything i can do?

Thanks,
Navaneeth

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to merge the two repos, that's possible. If you want Repo1 to somehow know that X1 corresponds to Y1, I don't believe that's possible in any way.

You can merge the repos by adding `Repo1` as a remote of `Repo2`.

```
git remote add repo-1
git fetch repo-1
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories repo-1/<branch-you-want-to-merge>
```

Given it sounds like there could be a huge diff, you might want to test this on a different branch before merging into develop/master.

Comment: I would like to merge X1 and Y1 :(

Comment: Then you can follow the steps in my answer.